# Change to andReturn() breaks C++ compilation

Tags: c++, ocmock

Commit https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/commit/a13a464b8d1c42b6526abfd968fba77f0687c8ac breaks compilation with C++ by making using of `__typeof__(_val)`. The error is:

`expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction`

It would seem to satisfy the same condition (the value is an ObjC object) by using the runtime, rather than the compiler with:

```
#define andReturn(aValue) _andReturn(({
  __typeof__(aValue) _val = (aValue);
  NSValue *_nsval = [NSValue value:&_val withObjCType:@encode(__typeof__(_val))];
  if (strcmp(@encode(__typeof(_val)), "@") == 0) {
      objc_setAssociatedObject(_nsval, "OCMAssociatedBoxedValue", *(__unsafe_unretained id *) (void *) &_val, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
  }
  _nsval;
}))
```

It seems the intention is to retain the object value inside the passed `NSValue`. I would submit a patch, but it doesn't appear that pull requests are accepted over Github.

Anyway, thanks!

Comment: PR at https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/pull/234

Comment: You missed to escape the newlines in your macro. `#define` is supposed to see the definition within a single line.

Comment: Side question: What makes you say that pull requests are not accepted? They are definitely welcome and many of them have been made and accepted. Is there anything that should be changed in the project settings or the documentation?

Comment: The linebreaks were removed for readability. The full version is in the pull request

Comment: @ErikDoernenburg contribution guide points in the direction of the forum, here and the mailing list. Quite a few old PRs on Github. That's just my interpretation from looking at the repo... In any case, I did make a PR

Comment: Adding a contribution guide was overdue. Thanks for the prodding. Have added one now.